# Machines used in banks to take a number

Tags: word-meaning, word-request

What do we call machines used in banks to take a number and wait for turn to come ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe it is simply called a **[ticket dispenser](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0054R1HWY)**, and they come in manual and electronic forms.

[image]